# TimeZone.setDefault for a thread in Java 8

Tags: java

We currently use TimeZone.setDefault to set the default timezone for a thread.
I know that with Java 8 calling this method sets the default timezone for the JVM.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to set the default timezone for a thread in Java 8 without having to rework a lot of code?

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the system defaulting at all. Use [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html): either a `ThreadLocal<TimeZone>`, or better, a `ThreadLocal<ZoneId>` with the `java.time` classes. Then you can fetch from there everywhere that you need the default.

Personally I'd try to avoid using a thread local at all, and pass around the context explicitly - or if you *do* want to have context implicitly, encapsulate all the context (e.g. for a web request) in an appropriate context type, rather than having separate thread locals for time zone, locale etc.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.